# Exception Handling a switch method

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to get a program I made to ask someone for a number between 1 and 13 in order to get them to make a selection. I'm trying to figure out how to handle if they want to be contrarian and enter a non-valid number or a character or string. Here's what I have so far...

```
try {
        attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());
        attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        System.out.println("Invalid option, please pick a valid option\n");
        showUnitSelection();
        attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());
        attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
}
```

Here's the method I'm using for a making the selection itself:

```
private static Unit selectUnit(int selection) {

    switch (selection) {
        case 1:
            return Unit.GreatSwords;
        case 2:
            return Unit.BlackOrcs;
        case 3:
            return Unit.Bestigor;
        case 4:
            return Unit.ChaosChosen;
        case 5:
            return Unit.MenAtArms;
        case 6:
            return Unit.Executioners;
        case 7:
            return Unit.GraveGuard;
        case 8:
            return Unit.Retributors;
        case 9:
            return Unit.StormVermin;
        case 10:
            return Unit.SwordMasters;
        case 11:
            return Unit.TombGuard;
        case 12:
            return Unit.WildWoodRangers;
        case 13:
            return Unit.Hammerers;
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not doing this right, if you don't mind I'd like to hear some suggestions to consider.

Comment: add a default case returning the Unit.Invalid if no other case match and check if it's invalid and show error to the user.

Comment: Use the default case, and then add a if statement to check if the default case was returned and if it was then you know its illegal input

Comment: why you catch NullPointerException, it can be IllegalArgumentException .

Comment: @Afgan: It's what my IDE was telling me

Comment: @Vikram & SteelToe: Thanks, I'll give it a shot.

Comment: @Dan refer my answer i might fit into your case

Comment: @Dan I personally think it is more preferable to use a default case with a if statement as exception handling uses more resources and becomes more messy. See my answer below which avoids all exception handling

Comment: `null` is not a `NullPointerException` - you only get an exception if you try to use it. You check for `null` with `== null`.

Answer (score 1):

I think code will look much prettier if you do it in this way:

```
public enum Unit{

        GreatSwords(1),
        BlackOrcs(2),
        Bestigor(3),
        ChaosChosen(4),
        MenAtArms(5),
        Executioners(6),
        GraveGuard(7),
        Retributors(8),
        StormVermin(9),
        SwordMasters(10),
        TombGuard(11),
        WildWoodRangers(12),
        Hammerers(13)

        private int index;

        public int getIndex() {
            return this.index;
        }

        public static getUnitByIndex(int index) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            return Stream.of(values())
            .filter(unit -> unit.getIndex() == index)
            .findFirst()
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid value");
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea over here would be to avoid nulls, therefore the best option would be to make a default case that return `Unit.Unknown` if the switch statement does not match anything. Then you can check if the input equals `Unit.Unknown` and if it does tell the user that it is invalid.

To do this, First add in a "Unknown" member to the Unit enum.

Then add in a default case to your switch statement like this:

```
     default:
        return Unit.Unknown;
```

Then in your original code change it to this:

```
       attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());
    attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
    //check if its valid
    if(attackerUnitName==Unit.Unknown){
    //unit is unknown ,tell the user the input was invalid
    } else {
    //input was valid, do what you want to do
    }
```

Comment: Why is `Unit.Unknown` better than `null`? They seem functionally pretty similar to me (especially if the use case is to just instantly check and replace it), which I'd argue makes `null` the better option.

Answer (score 0):

Your switch code would be like with default case-

```
    private static Unit selectUnit(int selection) {

        switch (selection) {
            case 1:
                return Unit.GreatSwords;
            case 2:
                return Unit.BlackOrcs;
            case 3:
                return Unit.Bestigor;
            case 4:
                return Unit.ChaosChosen;
            case 5:
                return Unit.MenAtArms;
            case 6:
                return Unit.Executioners;
            case 7:
                return Unit.GraveGuard;
            case 8:
                return Unit.Retributors;
            case 9:
                return Unit.StormVermin;
            case 10:
                return Unit.SwordMasters;
            case 11:
                return Unit.TombGuard;
            case 12:
                return Unit.WildWoodRangers;
            case 13:
                return Unit.Hammerers;
 default:throw new IllegalArgumentException(""Invalid option, please pick a valid option\n");
        }

    }
```

Your handling code would be like -

```
try {
        attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());
        attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage);
        showUnitSelection();
        attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());
        attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
}
```

Comment: Related: [When to throw an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77127)

Comment: good to [throw exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567932/throwing-exception-vs-returning-null-value-with-switch-statement) instead returning null

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Using exception handling for simple validation is an expensive operation, although it will work just fine.

```
attackingUnit = null;
while(attackingUnit == null){
   System.out.println("Invalid option, please pick a valid option\n");
   showUnitSelection();
   attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());   
}

attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
```

Update:
Modify you method to include default case (as per @SteelToe suggestion)

```
private static Unit selectUnit(int selection) {

switch (selection) {
    case 1:
        return Unit.GreatSwords;
    case 2:
        return Unit.BlackOrcs;
    case 3:
        return Unit.Bestigor;
    case 4:
        return Unit.ChaosChosen;
    case 5:
        return Unit.MenAtArms;
    case 6:
        return Unit.Executioners;
    case 7:
        return Unit.GraveGuard;
    case 8:
        return Unit.Retributors;
    case 9:
        return Unit.StormVermin;
    case 10:
        return Unit.SwordMasters;
    case 11:
        return Unit.TombGuard;
    case 12:
        return Unit.WildWoodRangers;
    case 13:
        return Unit.Hammerers;
    default:
        return Unit.Unknown;

  }


}
```

And do this:

```
attackingUnit = Unit.Unknown;
while(attackingUnit == Unit.Unknown){
   System.out.println("Invalid option, please pick a valid option\n");
   showUnitSelection();
   attackingUnit = selectUnit(input.nextInt());   
}

attackerUnitName = attackingUnit.getUnitName();
```

Comment: Are you reccomending returning nulls?

Comment: @SteelToe not really. I was just try to give a simple idea as I assuming he was trying a validation loop until user key in the correct input. Ofcourse you are right and that is the better way to do.

Comment: @SteelToe: Yeah I was trying to make it so that the user had to enter a valid option.